# how to search table through textbox?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have piece of query that search database from text box. 
My question is how can insert search result column by column to separated text box, I mean each column go to one textbox.

```
private void searchbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\hry\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Kargozini\Kargozini\khadamat.sdf");

     try
     {
         con.Open();
         string SearchQuerry = "SELECT ID, radif, Name, Type, Description, Price FROM Users WHERE ID = '"+searchtxt.Text+"'" ;
         SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand(SearchQuerry,con);
         com.ExecuteNonQuery();
         con.Close();
     }
     catch (SqlCeException ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

Comment: How many rows the select query can return.

Comment: First of all use paramterized query so you can avoid [sql injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596803/avoiding-an-sql-injection-attack). Then take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113025/how-to-display-data-from-database-into-textbox-and-update-it

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb748692.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that, your search will return only one row.
You can use datareader to achieve that. I modified your function with below code:

```
private void searchbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\hry\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Kargozini\Kargozini\khadamat.sdf");

     try
     {
         con.Open();
         string SearchQuerry = "SELECT ID, radif, Name, Type, Description, Price FROM Users WHERE ID = '"+searchtxt.Text+"'" ;
         SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand(SearchQuerry,con);

         SqlCeDataReader sqlReader = com.ExecuteReader();

         while (sqlReader.Read())
        {
            txtID.text = sqlReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
            txtRadif.text = sqlReader.GetValue(1).ToString();
            txtName.text = sqlReader.GetValue(2).ToString();
        }

        sqlReader.Close();
        com.Dispose();
        con.Close();
     }
     catch (SqlCeException ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

**Note: Your code is vulnerable to sqlinjection. Learn things to avoid it.**

Comment: i forgot to mention i use local database and for this line "  SqlDataReader sqlReader = com.ExecuteReader();
" i have this error   Error   1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataReader' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' C:\Users\hry\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Kargozini\Kargozini\searchform.cs 30 43 Kargozini

Comment: Try changing  SqlDataReader to SqlCeDataReader in SqlDataReader sqlReader = com.ExecuteReader();

Comment: i have another question the textbox approch just work for where that i have one return value i mean when i have more than one return value for example when my select query have more than one return value my question is how can show it for example in message box

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
private void searchbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection("Your String Connection");
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(@"Select Name, FileName From Table Where Name Like @Name", sql); 
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", string.Format("%{0}%", textBox1.Text));
}
```